# Give document fields different priority in search

Tags: elasticsearch, field

I have the following query:

```
'{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "ABC"}'
```

this will search all fields in given index\type
ex. Mytype has field1, field2, field3
this will match "ABC" to field1, field2, field3

Equal value is placed on the 3 fields
I need to prioritize the field ranking
so let's say the priority should be field2, field3, field1

How do I modify my search to set the field ranking/priority?

In my research I saw _score but that looks like its used to prioritize each doc instead of the fields.

Comment: better ex. using the field priority from above, lets say doc1 has a match with field3 and doc2 has a match with field2. even though doc1 and doc2 match, i need doc2 to have a higher score than doc1

Answer (score 8):

Here is update for newer Elasticsearch versions.
Query like this should boost results depending on respective fields content:

```
GET /_search
{ 
  "query":{
    "simple_query_string" : {
      "query": "ABC",
      "fields": [
        "field2^3",
        "field3^2",
        "field1^1"]
    }
  }  
}
```

Pay attention to "^3" after *field2*, this will boost results, so if "ABC" is found in all fields, they will be sorted as:

1. doc with *field2* containing "ABC"
2. doc with *field3* containing "ABC"
3. doc with *field1* containing "ABC"

Comment: Which version Elasticsearch supports that?

Comment: sorry, 3y later, I don't remember it :(

Answer (score 4):

Use a boost query and weight the fields in accordance with the prioritization you desire:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html

Comment: can we use the same with Nest ?